# drag and drop files from folder c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I am attempting to have ListView in my WPF application, which accepts drag and drop - both files and directories, but in case of directories it is supposed to get files from them, not them themselves.
My XAML:

```
<ListView ... AllowDrop="True" Drop="importListView_Drop">
...
</ListView>
```

My code behind:

```
private void importListView_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
    core.AddIntoImport(files);
}
```

This now produces outputs including directories and omitting files in them, f.e.

```
C:/Example/Files/MyFile.mp3
C:/Example/Files/SubDirectory/
...
```

While I'd like it to actually get all files from SubDirectory and not include SubDirectory itself. I could do this by myself: "is directory? - yes: exclude it and get all files from it instead" but the question is, is there some nicer way included in f.e. event args already?

Just to make myself more clear, following code does the job perfectly in WinForms app. Is there an alternative in WPF?

```
private void Form1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
    InsertImport(files);
}

private void Form1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this

```
var allFiles = files.Where(Directory.Exists)
                    .SelectMany(dir => Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                    .ToList();
```

Just be aware, this is will throw if you have don't have appropriate permissions on the sub directories. in such case you will have to do this more manually, and check-for / ignore errors

Comment: This gets all files from provided directory/directories, but does not remove directories themselves from import array/list and also doesn't take into consideration input in which both files and directories are included. Still, seems to be nice solution to getting files, but I was more curious about if framework can do this or not without me coding stuff on my own. Seems to be weird to me that WPF is that "dumb" and literally just collects paths and does nothing else.

Comment: Just to clarify - WinForms can do this by using DragEnter and DragDrop events, with very short code in both of them. WPF can't? Weird. Thats why I'm asking.

Comment: @JanToms yeah i might be misunderstanding the question

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do this in this way in the end btw...:

```
var files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
var importList = new List<string>();
foreach (string s in files)
{
    if (Directory.Exists(s))
        foreach (var f in Directory.GetFiles(s, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            importList.Add(f);
    else if (File.Exists(s))
        importList.Add(s);
}
```